# Function doesn't run or give returns when run from main

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, return

I'm currently trying to work with a .csv file with about ~70k rows and 19 columns. My code currently looks like this:

```
def read_data(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    headers = f.readline().strip().split(",")
    NiceRow = []

    x = 0
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        NiceRow.append(line.strip().split(","))
        line = f.readline()

        x += 1
    f.close()

    return headers, NiceRow
```

When I run this code under my main, it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't produce any visible data or returns, as I have tried to use the 'NiceRow' return in another function run after this in main, which causes an error because 'NiceRow' is not defined. When I run this code outside of my main function, it works, but only processes a small amount of the data. If anyone has any tips or knows why it won't produce data under main, or run the entire file, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html

Comment: There's no obvious problem with the code you've shown. If calling this code doesn't do what you expect, you should probably show the calling code, as it may not be doing what you intend, even if this code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As khelwood mentioned, use `csv` module:

```
import csv

def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:             # Open file
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')  # Use csv module
        lines = list(map(tuple, reader))       # Map csv data to a list of lines
        headers = lines[0]                     # Store headers
        NiceRow = lines[1:]                    # Store rest of lines in NiceRow
    return headers, NiceRow                    # Return headers and NiceRow
```